# iOS Daemon on jailbroken device - prevent sleep mode

Tags: iphone, ios, daemon, sleep, jailbreak

I am attempting to prevent sleep mode from my iOS Daemon app running in the background on a jailbroken device, using the following code:

```
- (void) disableSleepModeTimerEvent:(NSTimer *) timer; 
{
    [self writeTextFile]; // for debug purposes
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
}
```

As the simple statement of setting idleTimerDisabled to YES did not do the trick, i have put it in a method which is called by an NSTimer every 10 seconds as was advised in the answer of a similar question here on stackoverflow. Sadly that does not work either.

The timer-event is triggered (to check i write a file to a directory and see one appearing with 10 second intervals and every 10 seconds a file is added) but the device still goes to sleep. After manual wake the timer goes back to its business and starts writing the files again, but obviously disabling the sleep did not work.

I have a server running in this app and when something needs to be served i want to disable the sleep mode. After serving is done, sleep mode should be enabled again. Is this possible to achieve for a non visible app ?

Comment: How did you implement this?  It is a true **Launch Daemon**, or is it simply a normal UIApplication that you have put into the background by pressing the home button?

Comment: Hi Nate (are you the only one answering here? :-)) I have already found a fix for my problem - implemented MMPDeepSleepPreventer and this prevents the device from going to sleep even if the musicplayer is used. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Ronald: Don't you want to post this as an answer and accept it?

Comment: @Ronald : Please post your code for MMPDeepSleepPreventer.